# Antd table how to put text into cell in several lines

Tags: newline, cell, break, antd

In Antd is there a way to show the text in table cell into several lines.
I try to put `</br>`, \n, \r into the text.

Is there someone who has already find a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe a solution is to used a render of the cell column and format as we would like the text ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally here is my solution.

The text for each column contains an \n when there is necessary to have a new line.

After into the  table definition I put the style whiteSpace: 'pre':

```
<Table style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre'}} columns={columns} dataSource={data} title={title} .../>
```

Thats seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In the hopes that it's never too late to answer a question here :D

Use the renderer of the table cell, like below, where you can use HTML tags (I'm using React so it's formatted as ReactNode with <> </> parent elements):

```
const columns = [
    {
      title: "Start",
      dataIndex: "start",
      key: "start",
      render: (text) => <>
      <p>{text.split("@")[0]}</p>
      <p>{text.split("@")[1]}</p>
      </>
    },
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      render: (text) => text
    }]
```